# Android emulator Stuck with the step "Starting activity com.example.mum.MainActivity on device emulator-5554"

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am trying to be an android app developer. I have downloaded the ADT Bundle with Eclipse and SDK.

For first few days everything went fine(Compared to now). I created a calculator and a BMI calculator app and they were working fine. but for the last few days I am feeling annoyed taht none of the projects are running.

This is what it is doing.

```
--------------------------------Console----------------------------------------------------------
[2014-04-27 13:56:45 - mum] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-04-27 13:56:45 - mum] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-04-27 14:12:03 - mum] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-04-27 14:12:03 - mum] Uploading mum.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-04-27 14:12:04 - mum] Installing mum.apk...
[2014-04-27 14:14:19 - mum] Failed to install mum.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2014-04-27 14:14:19 - mum] (null)
[2014-04-27 14:14:20 - mum] Launch canceled!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And in the emulator I could see,"process system is not responding".

1. I cleaned the project. Project->Clean..

Now..

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2014-04-27 16:15:03 - mum] Android Launch!
[2014-04-27 16:15:03 - mum] adb is running normally.
[2014-04-27 16:15:03 - mum] Performing com.example.mum.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-04-27 16:15:07 - mum] Uploading mum.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-04-27 16:15:09 - mum] Installing mum.apk...
[2014-04-27 16:15:31 - mum] Success!
[2014-04-27 16:15:31 - mum] Starting activity com.example.mum.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And it is stuck with this step. Even previously the calculator, BMI calc apps did not open by itself. I manually clicked on the corresponding app icon from emulator to open. And for teh last few days, I started believing  "Force closing/Force Opening" corrupts the emulator.

Could you please advise how to overcome this situation?
Also could you please advise the best practices to be followed to make Android development process a painless one?

I am using..
OS: Windows 7 (64bit)
RAM: 6GB
Processor: i3 Core

Thanks a lot :)
Karthick

Comment: please add your main activity code and your manifest

Comment: Try to manually start your avd and check the `Wipe user data` option

Comment: Both comments are useful

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. If the emulator doesnt open the app by itself, **We have to set the Main class to e opened in the drop down box "Launch Action: Launch"** below the Project.

Usually Emulator is slow and it is so advisable to plug and use the real device if available.

Thanks.